# redirect old url to new url of same domain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I would like to redirect `https://www.example.com/page/jobseekers` to `https://www.example.com/jobseekers`

I used

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

Redirect /page/jobseekers /jobseekers
```

But its redirecting into `https://www.example.com/jobseekers?page/jobseekers`.

Comment: @anubhava No the same thing happening.

Answer (score 1):

Place this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^page/(jobseekers)/?$ /$1? [L,NC,R=301]

# other rules go below
```

Make sure to test in a new browser or clear browser cachhe before testing.

Comment: I want to redirect all pages that have shop in URL redirect to without shop URL like: https://example.com/shop/my-info/ redirected to https://example.com/my-info/ 
Please help me to make rule for this.

Comment: @PurushotamSharma: Use `RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]`